# ContraceptiveFragment( ) in ContraceptiveFragment cannot be applied to (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)

Tags: java, android

I'm new to programming, don't know what causes the error. I'm sharing a piece of code as well as error log. The bottom bold one is the error line.

```
private void initControls() {
    PregnancyModal motherDetails = Constants.getDatabase(getContext()).getMotherDetails(MemberDetailActivity.MEMBER_ID);
    if(motherDetails == null){
        Constants.getDatabase(getContext()).addPregnancyRecord(MemberDetailActivity.MEMBER_ID, HouseDetailFragment.selectedMember.getHouseID());
    }

    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.PregnancyHistory),new PregnancyHistory(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.maakebunyadimaloomat),new MotherBasicDetails(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.majoodaaurguzaishtasahatkemaloomat),new CurrentAndPastHealthInformation(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.guzarishtahamalkemaloomat),new PreviousPregnancyDetail(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.MotherPreviousHistory),new MotherPreviousHistory(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.deliverykemaloomat), new LaborandDeliveryInformation(getActivity())), "PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.checklistbaraymaa), new CheckListForMother(getActivity())), "PregnancyFragment");

    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.CheckupfromSkilledPerson),new CheckupfromSkilledPerson(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.Currentpregnancycheckupdetails),new Currentpregnancycheckupdetails(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.healthcentercheckuprequard),new HealthCenterCheckUpRecord(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.deliverykaymuqamkehidayat),new PlaceofDeliveryDetail(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.ImportantThingsRelatedtoChildandMothersHealth),new ImportantThingsRelatedtoChildandMothersHealth(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");
    **accordion.addTab(new AccordionTab(getString(R.string.contracaptive),new ContraceptiveFragment(getActivity())),"PregnancyFragment");**

}
```

Error log

```
Error:(94, 77) error: constructor ContraceptiveFragment in class ContraceptiveFragment cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: FragmentActivity
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a constructor with `FragmentActivity` as parameter in `ContraceptiveFragment`. Add this in your `ContraceptiveFragment` class:

```
public ContraceptiveFragment(FragmentActivity activity){
    // TODO: initialisations
}
```

Comment: what other error.. Also post your ContraceptiveFragment code